# Using Position Fixed only vertically avoiding horizontal movement

Tags: javascript, html, css

I realized a set of arrows like those in the picture : 
[image]

I need the arrows to move vertically when the page will be scrolled down and up: I can archive this using position: fixed, but the problem is that this CSS format will add constraints also for the horizontal scoll, which wouldn't be allowed on this website. Is there any trick to avoid this problem ?

This is a part of my code :

CSS:

```
#arrowR{
  position: fixed !important;
  margin-left: -50px !important;
}
#textR{
  color: black  !important;
  font-weight: bold !important;
  position: fixed !important;
}

#arrowL{
  position: fixed !important;
  margin-right: -50px !important;
}

div#RCont {
    float: right;
}

div#LCont {

    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 40%;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

div#RContBack {
  float: left;
}

div#LContBack {
  float: right !important;
      margin-top: 40% !important;
      margin-right: 70px !important;

}
```

Then my HTML code :

```
<div id="cont_ArrowL" ng-show ="!routingCtrl.isFirstElement()" >
   <div id="LContBack">
      <span id="textR">
      Indietro
      <span>
   </div>
   <div id="RContBack">
      <md-icon md-svg-src="./image/left.svg" aria-label="android " id="arrowR"  class="goPrevious" ng-click="routingCtrl.previousPage()">Indietro</md-icon>
   </div>
</div>
<div id="cont_ArrowR" ng-show ="!routingCtrl.isLastElement()">
   <div id="LCont">
      <span id="textR">
      Avanti
      <span>
   </div>
   <div id="RCont">
      <md-icon md-svg-src="./image/right.svg" aria-label="android " id="arrowR" class="goNext"  ng-click="routingCtrl.nextPage()"></md-icon>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to clarify your question.  This... `but the problem is that this CSS format will add constraints also for the horizontal scoll, which wouldn't be allowed on this website` makes no sense.  Try to demonstrate your issue with a working example, rather than copy/paste your own code.  Read how to create a [mcve]

Comment: You are right, I will express my self better: The problem is that I need to use fixed position, but I am looking for a way to block the horizontal effect, permitting only the vertical one

Comment: Please update the question to demonstrate the problem you have, so we can help you fix it.

Comment: So is your page horizontally scrollable? If so, the only way to make this work is perhaps to only make your content scrollable itself and position all three elements relative next to each other.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to detect horizontal scroll and then change position fixed attribute

```
var lastScrollLeft = 0;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var documentScrollLeft = $(document).scrollLeft();
    if (lastScrollLeft != documentScrollLeft) {
        console.log('scroll horizontol');
        lastScrollLeft = documentScrollLeft;
         $("#Arrow").css({'position' : 'absolute'})
    }
});
```

now problem is that it sets position absolute for both horizontal & vertical movement so detect when it comes back and set fixed again

```
scrollpos = $(document).scrollLeft();
if (scrollpos == 0){$("#Arrow").css({'position' : 'fixed'})}
```